# WebClient.DownloadString method returns non-existent HTML code from a simple TXT file

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, webclient

I'm using Xamarin Android (Monodroid) to make a mobile app using C#. I simply want to download a plain text file into a string. It is to compare the program's version with the latest ([this](http://www.xn--demirbatakip-bnc.com/program/ver.txt) file). So I'm using WebClient's DownloadString method. Code is as follows:

```
string version = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(new System.Uri("http://www.xn--demirbatakip-bnc.com/program/ver.txt"));
```

Weird thing is, this used to work as it should, before. I don't know what corrupted the code (new Android API maybe?) but now it downloads the following instead:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1; url=http://www.xn--demirbatakip-bnc.com/program/ver.txt&arubalp=feadb3ba-b2c2-4e6d-89cf-3a4dae437e'/>
</head>
</html>
```

It's just a 5 character text file. I can't understand how could it be converted into this weird HTML code.

It was showing this behaviour only in debug mode before, so I wouldn't mind much. Now this also extends into release mode. What is going on here?

Comment: Weird, works perfectly good on my machine. can you try testing your code on a different machine (preferably with a different external IP)? maybe you made too many calls to the server so it  thinks you are trying to mess with the system

Comment: Hmm, so could it be about my connection speed? Wi-fi signal on the machine is kind of weak (It's throwing timeout errors in webservice calls, from time to time). But my program should work in bad conditions like this.